# Focus event firing after a focus inside of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a hidden input to keybind my app with it but without triggering events when i write on other input-fields

```
-clicks on element {
  -hide element
  -creates an input text-field(to edit the element)
  -focus the input
  - on blur or submit  changes the element and remove the input
 }
```

but if you add this new event  :

```
 - click anywhere in the container {
   -focus the hidden app input (so it can use keybinding)
 }
```

when user clicks on the element it ends firing the blur event without letting the user edit it first because its activating the second block event.
so it's either skipping  the focus part of the first block
or the focus of the second block is activating after the focus on the first one

I'm maybe using the wrong approach to solving it
but I don't know why it's behaving that way.

actual code:

```
$("#hiddenInput").focus()
var elem = $("#nameClip");
function evenConditional(id) {
    if ($(id).val() !== "") {
        elem.text($(id).val())
        storedObj.name = $(id).val();
    }
    $(id).parent().remove();
    elem.show();
}
$("#name").on("click", function() {
    elem.hide();
    elem.after(
        $("<form/>").append(
            $("<input/>").addClass("rename")
        )
    );
    $(".rename").focus();
});
$(".rename").blur(function() {
    evenConditional(this);
});
$(".rename").closest("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    evenConditional(this);
});
/// regaining focus on click 
$(".container").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#hiddenInput").focus()
});
```

css:

```
#hiddenInput {
    position:absolute;
    top: -2000;
}
```

Comment: Please show real code, not pseudo-code. But I don't think you can focus on a hidden input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `#name` element is in the `.container` element, when you click on it, the click event bubbles up to the container, causing the click-event handler for the container to get executed.

One way to fix this would be to stop the click event from bubbling:

```
$("#name").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
```

There can be side effects from doing that though. Particularly, there may be other event handlers that will not get executed because of that. Such as handlers that close opened menus.

The other option would be to place conditional logic in the click handler for the container so it does not execute if the click originated with the name element.

```
$(".container").on("click", function(e) {
    var nameElement = $("#name")[0];
    if ((e.target != nameElement) and !$.contains(nameElement , e.target)) {
        $("#hiddenInput").focus();
    }
});
```